# Travis CI integration with Artifactory

Tags: travis-ci, devops

I am trying to use Artifactory to store files from GitHub as binaries to Artifactory.

But vm created by travis is not able to communicate with my local machine.

As travis assigns build environment as vm on `ec2/packet/gce` if particular sudo and dist options are selected, by default vm on `ec2/packet` if none of the option is selected.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you need Travis to communicate with your local machine? What is Artifactory and what is your goal with it? Edit your answer and tell us a bit more please